# Again on build systems. Let's talk about complete correctness

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja, tup

Recently I tried tup and I am VERY impressed by its correctness and speed, and the fact that monitoring the file system makes the tool really robust. It is also very easy to understand.
It never gets anything wrong, and when it does, it will show me. I would like to find a tool that is more mainstream and cross-platform friendly as long as it meets the requirements below.

My questions are:

1. Do you know any alternative build tool that has:

   - O(1) rebuilds.
   - Completely correct dependency tracking.
   - (Optional) Takes advantage of filesystem access.

EDIT: This is not a  subjective "recommend me a tool" question, it is give me names of tools that meet these requirements because I would like to further research on how they behave for my use cases.

Comment: I am not sure if the close vote *reasons* completely fit but this does look like *evangelism* cleverly disguised as a *question*. That being said `tup` does look very interesting. ;o)

Comment: no pun intended. Seriously. I find that tup does not work completely correctly in windows and I wish there would be a better or equal more mainstream system. Maybe cmake + ninja? I do not know. But I am seriously looking for one that also works on windows. It is really comfortable to work with tup. I am not in any way affiliated to the project.

Comment: It is really annoying when there is some wrong dependency and you regenerate and rebuild. It happened to me with CMake several times. With tup that is history. But, on the other side, if compiling on windows + packaging is a must... cmake is the only option.